# MS Access: Printing blank pages despite correct margins

Tags: ms-access, printing, ms-access-2016

- I am printing warehouse slot labels to a label printer with a 4" x 2" roll of labels.
- I have an MS Access report which divides each label into its own page.
- The labels are just an alphanumeric string of 5 digits.
- The detail section of my report is just 3.5" wide.
- The margins are set to 0.1" Left and Right.
- Vertical margins are set to 0.25" and are not an issue.
- Printing labels yields a blank label after every correctly printed label.
- All labels do eventually get printed, but with double the amount of time and labels used.
- I receive the following error message whenever I open Print Preview or close Page Setup:

> The section width is greater than the page width, and there are no items in the additional space, so some pages may be blank.

So here is my question: Why are my correctly sized labels printing off the page?

TIA

Comment: What do you have for page settings?  Anything in column layout?  The section width warning makes me wonder if it is attempting two columns--but that wouldn't explain the blanks.  Do you have a field that is completely filling the detail section and has a border?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming issue, it is report design.

Comment: I posted this here because I had difficulty finding the correct reason for the problem and imagined that it could be something programmatic or have a programmatic solution. I was under the impression that configuration questions were regularly asked and answered, even if code was not the immediate question or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Print Preview -> Page Setup -> Columns -> Column Size -> Check the box marked "Same As Detail"

Apparently, Access automatically assigned a column width that was the same size as the entire page (4"). This conflicted with the page's borders and triggered the blank pages.